# Remove tag inside another tag beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

uHow can I extract text inside a tag like this:

```
<div><blockquote type="cite" class=""><p>Find me<\p>
<blockquote cite="mid:609415CB-0979-47C1-9A75-CE1BE65939A0@wiwacom.fr" type="cite" class=""><p>Not me<\p>
      <blockquote type="cite" class=""><p>Not me too<\p>
      </blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

And I want to get :

```
Find me
```

With python and beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.find` to get your required text.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div><blockquote type="cite" class=""><p>Find me</p>
<blockquote cite="mid:609415CB-0979-47C1-9A75-CE1BE65939A0@wiwacom.fr" type="cite" class=""><p>Not me<\p>
      <blockquote type="cite" class=""><p>Not me too<\p>
      </blockquote>
</blockquote></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div").find("p").text)
```

**Output:**

```
Find me
```

Note: You have some invalid `p` tags `<\p> ==> </p>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.